# Unbox value of type object to long

Tags: c#, unboxing

I had a variable of type object and I wanted to convert it to int in advance.?

prev code

```
val = Math.Max(((int)DatabaseHelper.ExecuteScalerCommand(query)), numbering.StartValue);
```

Now I need to convert it to type long. I try to use `long.tryparse()`

```
long t = 0;
long.TryParse(DatabaseHelper.ExecuteScalerCommand(query).ToString(), out t);
var val = Math.Max(t, numbering.StartValue);
```

is there a better way to handle this problem?

Comment: What's wrong with this? It is not working?

Comment: it works, but it's not so clean!

Comment: I agree with the deleted answer. If `object x;` holds a box with an `int`, that is if `(int)x` works and unboxes the `object x` to `int`, then the correct thing to do is `(long)(int)x`. However the last conversion, from `int` to `long`, will often be implicit, as in `long t = (int)x;` (same as `long t = (long)(int)x;` or `var t = (long)(int)x;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try using this**

```
long id = Convert.ToInt64(ObjectToConvert)
```

and might be prone to error unlike TryParse() in the datatype

Comment: like invalid cast, TryParse() is handling this when it can't cast the value, it return 0 or the instead of error

Comment: if i am sure that it has long type, it seems that it's safe to use convert.toint64()

Comment: If you know `ObjectToConvert` always has type `int`, it is better to use `long id = (int)ObjectToConvert;`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, I agree with that but for some times c# does't always happy with like this (int)ObjectToConvert specifically when the object value is coming from database using SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() or SqlCommand.Execute()

Comment: @Jade One should be careful to check the compile-time type and actual run-time type. For example the solution could be `long t = ((SqlInt32)x).Value;` which is like `long t = (int)(SqlInt32)x;`. Using the `Convert` class is a bad idea in my opinion unless the run-time type varies.

Comment: No more arguments, but you will experience it someday (well i used VS2010 and .Net Framework 4.0).